# Could not create parent directory for lock file

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting error: "Could not create parent directory for lock file C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9\gradle-3.3-all.zip.lck"

Any help is appreciated!